# Selecting Quality Gate for SonarQube Analysis in Jenkinsfile

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that, among other things, performs SonarQube analysis on my build and passes it through 'Quality Gate' stage. The analysis is placed on the SonarQube server where I can see all the details. The relevant pieces of code for the analysis and Quality gate are below (not mine, it is from [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/)):

```
stage('SonarCloud') {
      steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {

            sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar '

        }
      }
    }

stage("Quality Gate") {
      steps {
        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES') { // If analysis takes longer than indicated time, then build will be aborted
            waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
            script{
                def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Waiting for analysis to be completed
                if(qg.status != 'OK'){ // If quality gate was not met, then present error
                    error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Currently, once the analysis is completed and placed on the server, it uses server's default quality gate. I wonder if I can specify which quality gate to use with my analysis, before proceeding to 'Quality gate' stage? (I have another quality gate set up, with different acceptance criteria, that I would like to use for 'Quality Gate' stage).

Altering the default quality gate cannot be done because other people are using it (hence why I have my own quality gate set up).

I have looked into 'ceTaskUrl' link, that can be found in report-task.txt file, but didn't get far with it (no variable that I can see, and use, to select quality gate).

I also found this [Jenkinsfile](https://gist.github.com/vdupain/832964527b4b8d7d4c648169dae8c656). I tried to use some of its code, with additional googling on top of it, in hopes to access and alter quality gate, but also didn't get far with it.

It is worth mentioning that I do not have admin privileges at the SonarQube server I am using. However, I can request for a new quality gate to be configured as required, in case it is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using the WebAPI but for that you need **Administer Quality Gate** permission.

Please find more details here in this answer.

[How to assign Quality Gate dynamically to project from the script [SonarQube 6.5]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692029/how-to-assign-quality-gate-dynamically-to-project-from-the-script-sonarqube-6-5/63751037#63751037)

Or in case you don’t get the proper permission, then the alternate way is to use sonarqube UI, where you can specify which Quality Gate should be used for which project.

Comment: I see. Am I right in understanding, that ```sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar '``` is not gonna cut it, if I were to use this method? I would need to create a project first, associate it with quality gate of my choice and then analyse it, is that right?

Comment: Correct. You have to first create the project, associate with quality gate using webapi and then analyse it.

Comment: Makes sense. That should be enough to go with. Thank you!

Comment: There used to be one sonar analysis properties **sonar.qualitygate** but it has been deprecated and removed a long time ago.